# Firebird - string right truncation

Tags: firebird2.5

I am facing a peculiar Problem while trying to store a string value more than 80 characters
In my stored procedure, i have defined a string as Varchar(100) and assign a value with more than 80 characters.

In case if the assigned string length is < 80 characters.. it is working fine, In case if the length crosses 79 characters then  iam  getting string truncate error.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE returns (vals varchar(3))

as
declare variable Vallen integer;

declare variable pos integer;

declare variable val varchar(3);

declare variable distinct_Vals varchar(100);

begin

   distinct_Vals = '123 456 789 012 345 678 901 234 567 890 123 456 789 012 345 678 901 234 567 890 1';

   valLEN = UDF_STRLEN(distinct_Vals);

   POS = 1;

    WHILE ( :POS < :ValLen) DO

    BEGIN

        Val = UDF_SUBSTRLEN(:distinct_Vals,:POS,3);

        POS = POS + 4;

        Vals = :Val;

        suspend;
end

end
```

Suspend is for just displaying the individual values

I am using Firebird 2.5  with ISO8859_1 character set.

Any help or Suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Regards,
Srian.

Comment: I suppose it is Problem with the UDF i am using i.e., UDF_SUBSTRLEN is defined as CSTRING(80) (BOTH in and out parameter).

Comment: Sounds like it. You might want to check the UDF itself, it might support larger lengths, but then you will need to update the declaration in the database. BTW: Why not just us the builtin functions of Firebird?

Comment: Mark... I fixed it.. it was because of UDF only.. after changing the parameters size, it is working. Regarding your suggestion of using built-in functions, initially we were using them, since there were some limitation we moved to UDFs.

Comment: Could you post your own solution as an answer, it might be helpful for others as well.